# Dark mode becoming undefined when clicking off an input field

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby, darkmode

I have a site implemented using Gatsby and React. I'm using [use-dark-mode](https://github.com/donavon/use-dark-mode) to implement dark mode on my site. The styles are defined in my CSS as follows.

```
body.light-mode {
    --text-color: var(--text-color-light);
}
body.dark-mode {
    --text-color: var(--text-color-dark);
}
```

I can access the darkmode value using a react hook, e.g. `darkmode.value`. `darkmode.value` can be either `true` or `false`.

I'm having a very weird issue. I have a simple HTML input, `<input/>`. I click on the input, and enter at least one character. The moment that I click off the input field, `darkmode.value` becomes `undefined`.

How could the action of deselecting a text field (only after entering at least one character) change the value of the darkmode hook to `undefined`?

Edit:
Unsure whether this counts as a minimal example, but I think it's reproducible:

1. Initialise new Gatsby project with `npm init gatsby`
2. Install dark mode package `npm install @fisch0920/use-dark-mode` (this is a fork of the `use-dark-mode` package due to compatibility with newer versions of React)
3. Copy the following to `/src/pages/index.js`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import useDarkMode from '@fisch0920/use-dark-mode';

const IndexPage = () => {
  const darkMode = useDarkMode(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("darkMode.value: " + darkMode.value);
  }, [darkMode.value]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input/>
      <h1 onClick={darkMode.toggle}>
        Click me
      </h1>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

4. Open console, and see that the darkmode state is correctly being toggled when clicked. Now, when you go to enter text into the text field, then click off it, notice that "darkMode.value: undefined" is printed to console.

Comment: Some sort of naming conflict perhaps - like the input field having `darkmode` as ID or name ...?

Comment: But, we are not really in the guessing game here. You are supposed to present a proper [mre] of your issue, when asking this kind of question.

Comment: @CBroe Will try to figure out a minimal reproducible example, I'll update the post if I do manage to get one. 


The thing is the input field doesn't have an id or anything, it's just a plain input: `<input/>`.

Comment: How are you handling your input value? Maybe your dark mode and input info are in the same state.

Comment: @CBroe Added a reproducible example

Comment: @WilliamRizzi Not handling the input value at all. I added a reproducible example to the post, if that helps at all.

Comment: `use-dark-mode` isnt maintened anymore and you shoould look for something else to use. You can create your own dark mode component (https://dev.to/hr21don/dark-mode-with-gatsbyjs-for-dummies-4g9f) ou use another package.

Comment: While looking into `use-dark-mode` , I noticed an eventListener for the 'change' event(src/index.js:41) that appears to be triggered by changes in the input. It seems that the element passed as an option to useEventListener is an object(?) and not a real element. The event listener package being used is @use-it/event-listener. I would recommend considering another module that is currently maintained for better support.

Comment: @WilliamRizzi Appreciate your time. You're right, I have moved away from this particular module and I'm on the hunt for another. It's kinda crazy that there doesn't seem to be one commonly used npm module that implements something so prevalent nowadays as dark mode.

Comment: Although I've never used Gatsby for a website, looking into the internet it seens there is a pluggin for it https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-dark-mode/. You can implement it yourself if it doesnt work for your case.